# Using Rccp as a C++ STL without using using R

Tags: c++, rcpp

I understand that Rcpp is an R package for integration between C++ and R. I have a code which uses Rcpp for this. But I am looking to use the C++ code directly. Is it possible to get Rcpp as any usual C++ STL so that I can use the functions of Rcpp as it is (eg: the `as` in Rcpp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
R> cppFunction("double mysum(std::vector<double> x) { \
                   double s = std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0.0); return s;}")
R> mysum(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3))
[1] 0.6
R>
```

There are plenty of STL examples in the documentation, the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) and other places as *e.g.* my talks. Or of course [the Rcpp book](http://www.rcpp.org/book).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Actually I want to move completely out of R, and just use the C++ code. So in my C++ code I want to use something like `#include <Rcpp.h>` and not use R or its packages at all. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Yes, but _you can only really call Rcpp code from R_ as it itself is meant, designed and built as an R extension.  It is not standalone or separable from R.  Now, some of its code _may_ work when pulled in as a header-library but you're on your own there.